# Interesting "evil-twin" svn merge

Tags: svn, svn-merge, tree-conflict

Today I encountered a really interesting problem while trying to do a what seemed a simple enough merge.

Suppose we have two branches, B1 and B2, where B2 was branched from B1 at some time T1.

On each of these branches a new "F" folder was created (independently) so that after a while each branch contained different files (luckily) in their own version of "F".

However, when you try to merge B1 into B2 (or viceversa), you will get a tree conflict, as even if both branches have an "F" folder, it's totally different (svn-speaking) to each other.

It may be the case of the "evil twin" - however, in this case, branches B1 and B2 have totally different files and folders beneath the common "F".
As an example, B1 can have "F\a.txt" and "F\b.txt" while B2 "F\c.txt".

What I want to do now is to merge B1 into B2 so that after the merge B2 contains "F\a.txt", "F\b.txt" and "F\c.txt". After this, I also want to be able to merge B2 back into B1 but without conflicts (so B1 would also contain "F\a.txt", "F\b.txt" and "F\c.txt").

(This is actually a real-world problem which I simplified. The B1 branch is the trunk and B2 is a feature branch I need to prepare so that the integrator doesn't have to deal with conflicts)

The only solution - kind of ugly, it's like svn is against as - I found is to svn delete B2/F, then merge B1/F, then re-add B2/F.

Thank you!

PS. We are currently using Tortoise SVN 1.6.16 (in case it matters)

Comment: It may help you : http://little418.com/2009/05/svn-local-obstruction-incoming-add-upon-merge.html

Comment: I have seen that already:) The problem is that after I do the merge (let's say B1 into B2), the tree conflict prevents any file contained by B1/F to be copied to B2/F - so I cannot do the trick with the svn resolve --accept working. I can keep the local "F" folder - but what should happen with the files from the other branch?